# How to add a separate single field in mongodb schema

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I have made a model for the releases, which has fields (artist,single,genre,link,image) etc.

As this model will make a collection of documents as this json.

**I need to add one separate field to save MONTH like in the (image 2) "APRIL" is written**

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Model file is follows

```
const releasesSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    description:{
      type:String,
      required:false
    },
    artist: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    single: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    genre: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    link: {
      required: false,
      type: String,
    },
    filename: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
    fileId: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
    isFavourite: {
      default:false,
      required: false,
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
const Release = mongoose.model("releases", releasesSchema);
export default Release;
```